# sending variables from .sh file to .yml

Tags: bash, shell, github, yaml

I am trying to run shell script from yml file and insert variables generated from shell script onto yml file ..which I am not able to .
here is yml file 
   version: 0.2

```
phases:
  install:
    - bash build.sh
    - cd $DIR
```

this is what build script has

```
#!/bin/bash
  directory=$(git log -1 --pretty=%B | awk '{print $1;}')
echo "   directory: $directory"
build up -d -e DIR:$directory
export DIR=$directory
```

all that shell script doing iss getting git commit message ..and I want that to be transferred yml file from which shell script is being called

Comment: Do you care about the file in question keeping its current form? Since YAML is a superset of JSON, you could express this in JSON and use `jq` to do the transform.

Comment: Thanks for your response @CharlesDuffy ..yes file should be YAML as i am trying to implement some functionality using Travis CI which works only on  YAML files

Comment: Everything that works on YAML files also works on JSON files (except where dependent on data structures JSON cannot represent), because **every JSON file is also a YAML file**. The one is a superset of the other. Thus, by "every form", I didn't mean to ask if you need it to stay valid YAML -- I meant to ask if you meant it to stay valid *block-form* YAML (a specific means of formatting YAML that *is not* also valid JSON).

Comment: (The naive approach to answering this question is just to perform string substitution, but that allows ill-formed values to inject arbitrary content; syntax-aware parsing and generation is much safer).

Comment: Assuming the shell script is executed in a subshell, no variable that you set (or export) will become visible to the parent shell. You would need to `source build.sh`. Perhaps... I depending on how your yaml get turned into actual execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A Representation Valid As Both YAML *and JSON*

Consider the following, which any valid YAML parser will accept:

```
{"phases": {"install": ["bash build.sh", "cd $DIR"]}}
```

---

#### Updating This With `jq`

```
dir=/foo/bar/baz  ## this can be anything
jq --arg dir "$dir" '
.phases.install = [ (.phases.install | map(sub("[$]DIR"; ($dir | @sh))))]
' <in.json >out.json
```

...will properly replace `$DIR` with *a correctly quoted version of* the directory name for any possible such name. (This does require that `$DIR` not be used in a quoted context; if you were using `"$DIR"`, for instance, quote characters added by the `@sh` helper in `jq` would be treated as literal).

**And yes, since all JSON is valid YAML, this result *is* YAML.**